# dotnetbrowser - how to save specific image c#

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

How to save in file a specific tag image of the site loaded inside the dotnetbrowser without get image from url? C#.

> Like:
>   e.Browser.GetDocument().GetElementByName("imgA")).Save("C:\aaaa.jpg");

Answer (score 1):

Based on their API documentation, `GetElementByName` is returning `DOMElement` object. And there's no method called `Save()` inside `DOMElement` object.

Assume I have html like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="500" height="333">
</body>
</html>
```

So first, you need to get `TextContent` (which is image url) from `DOMElement`

```
var url = e.Browser.GetDocument().GetElementByName("img").GetAttribute("src");
```

Then you can load image url into Browser. To download file using DotNetBrowser you should create `DownloadHandler` instance. Here's example how to download file using DotNetBrowser: https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110026-file-downloads

---

However personally i'd prefer to use WebClient instead of DotNetBrowser `DownloadHandler.` So you can download image from url like this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) client.DownloadFile(url, "C:\\aaaa.jpg");
```

More about `WebClient.DownloadFile:` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2